# installing tomcat on top of ubuntu in docker

Tags: java, linux, docker, ubuntu, tomcat

I am new to docker and trying to install tomcat on top of ubuntu using a Dockerfile.
but getting error building an image from the Dockerfile.

Error saying...

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   12.8kB
Step 1/12 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> d13c942271d6
Step 2/12 : MAINTAINER xyz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 83dbc04930a4
Step 3/12 : RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1e167fd46a0e
Step 4/12 : WORKDIR /opt/tomcat/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 26c7316b8e12
Step 5/12 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b0138decc33d
Step 6/12 : RUN curl -O https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.50/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.50.tar.gz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eda41a539c78
Step 7/12 : RUN tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.50.tar.gz
 ---> Running in cc9f646b2bb2

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.50.tar.gz' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

and my code is

```
FROM ubuntu: latest
MAINTAINER ganeshthirumani
RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat/
WORKDIR /opt/tomcat/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -O https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.50/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.50.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.50.tar.gz 
RUN mv apache-tomcat-8.5.50/* /opt/tomcat/.
WORKDIR /opt/docker-tomcat/tomcat/webapps
RUN curl -O -L https://github.com/AKSarav/SampleWebApp/raw/master/dist/SampleWebApp.war
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I am trying to understand the code as it was suggested by one of my friends,

as my understanding:

at line

1. fixing the base image as ubuntu
2. this is the metadata of the person who is maintaining the code, it may be organizational
   3,4. working directory, here we have two working directories, one to run docker commands and another is to deploy the war file
3. is to install the curl on docker
   6-10. I did not understand anything.
4. is to make the localhost to run the tomcat
5. cmd to run the container

I am trying but I was not able to what It means...
it would be helpful if anyone respond...

Thank you so much...

Comment: `https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.50/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.50.tar.gz` this returns a 404 for me, you're downloading the html for the 404 page and trying to uncompress that, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you @ 
Federico klez Culloca

but for me by using curl, I tried on terminal 
curl -I https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.50/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.50.tar.gz
HTTP/1.1 302 Found

why is this so?

Comment: Because you're not following the redirect (you probably meant `curl -L`, with an upper `L` as option). If you follow the redirect you'll get the 404. The result is the same though, you're trying to unzip an html file. The currently correct link is https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.73/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.73.tar.gz